# How to fetch an attributes from my class with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 class, 2 are simple class and 1 combines the two of them.

```
public class Person:Base
{
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
}

public class Roles:Base
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class RolePerson:Base
{
    public int pID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person PersonID { get; set; }
    public int rID { get; set; }
    public virtual Roles RoleID { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have method that would select RolePerson witch would grab all member of pID with the id that i provide in the argument, and return the RoleID field.

this is how my method look like

```
    public IEnumerable<Roles> PersonRoles(int personID)
    {
        return db.RolePerson.Where<RolePerson>((p) => p.pID == personID);
    }
```

How can i say to return the role and not the roleperson.

Update:

My base class is as follow

```
public abstract class Base
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Boolean isValid { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdOn { get; set; }
        public int createdID { get; set; }
        public Person createdPerson { get; set; }
        public DateTime updatedOn { get; set; }
        public int updatedID { get; set; }
        public Person updatedPerson { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return the role"? Do you want to return a list of `Roles` instead of `RolePerson`?

Comment: Yes sorry, that is what I mean,

Comment: But your `Roles` class does not have a `RoleID` property. How is it related to `RolesPerson`?

Comment: I have a property called ID which is in my base object,

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx goodle around for foreign keys with Entity Framework etc.

Comment: @Jseb Update the question to include this information.

Comment: ... that base class ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a select statement in the end.

```
return d.RolePerson.Where(p => p.PId == personID).Select(r=> r.RoleID);
```

Comment: This still returns a list of `RolePerson` instead of a list of `Roles`, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: @AmateurProgrammer No it will not return a list of RolePerson. Select will extract the property mentioned, in this case RoleId, which is type of Roles according to the class and return an IEnumerable of that.

Comment: Thank, I tested it and yes that what the syntax i was looking for, thank, will accept once i can

Comment: @AnilGoel Oh yes. Sorry. My bad.